# Liberar memoria de array dinamico de punteros en arbol no-binario

Tags: c, array, punteros

Tengo esta estructura:

```
typedef struct Nodo 
{
    int valor;
    int numSubNodos;
    struct Nodo *padre;
    struct Nodo **hijo;
} Nodo;
```

Para llenarla como árbol No binario des-balanceado, o mejor dicho que un nodo pueda tener varios hijos y no todos los nodos tengan el mismo número de hijos.

La función que utilizo cada vez que voy a crear un nodo es esta:

```
Nodo *crearNodo (Nodo *padre, int numSubNodos, int valor)
{

    Nodo *node;
    node =  (Nodo *)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    //printf( "Nodo creado: %d\n", node);
    node->valor = valor;
    node->padre = padre;
    if (numSubNodos > 0)
        node->hijo =  malloc( numSubNodos * sizeof(Nodo*) );    
    else
        node->hijo = NULL;
    return node;

}
```

Y para liberar la memoria utilizo esta otra función:

```
int freeNodos (Nodo *node)
{

    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodo->numSubNodos; i++)
        freeNodos(nodo->hijo[i]);
    free (node);
}
```

El programa almacena los valores y los imprime, sin embargo al momento de liberar la memoria el programa se detiene y dice que debe cerrarse.

Entonces me pregunto: ¿Estoy declarando bien el array hijos? y ¿Cómo puedo liberar la memoria?. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo apunta a que te falta la línea que te marco con el comentario.

```
Nodo *crearNodo (Nodo *padre, int numSubNodos, int valor)
{

    Nodo *node;
    node =  (Nodo *)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    //printf( "Nodo creado: %d\n", node);
    node->valor = valor;
    node->padre = padre;
    node->numSubNodos = numSubNodos; // <<--- AQUI
    if (numSubNodos > 0)
        node->hijo =  malloc( numSubNodos * sizeof(Nodo*) );    
    else
        node->hijo = NULL;
    return node;

}
```

Y bueno, para rematar la jugada... te falta un `free`:

```
int freeNodos (Nodo *node)
{

    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodo->numSubNodos; i++)
        freeNodos(nodo->hijo[i]);
    free(node->hijo); // <<--- AQUI
    free(node);
}
```

Piensa que si haces dos reservas de memoria para crear un nodo necesitas forzosamente dos liberaciones para no tener fugas de memoria.

Por cierto, nota que `freeNodos` debería retornar un entero y no retorna nada.

Comment: jejeje XD que fallo tan importante. Muchas gracias! ya lo corregí y funciona perfecto